# Sum of exponential square series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-sum

I have a infinite sum which I wonder if it will converge to a simpler function

$f(r) = \Sigma_n r^{n^2} , r<1$,

I also interested in case $r$ is a complex number on unity circle $r = e^{j\omega}$.

Comment: It converges but not to elementary functions.

Answer (score 6):

By definition, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{n^2}=\theta_3(0,r)$. See [Jacobi elliptic $\theta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).