# Infinite sum of squared exponential $\exp(-n^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What does the below infinite sum of squared exponential $e^{-n^2}$ converge to?
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-n^2}}$$

From Normal Distribution, I can deduce that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-x^2} dx}  = \sqrt{\pi}$$

What happens in the discrete case?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1120266/516816) talks about infinite sum, but in general case, not for exponential and also it redirects to a Wikipedia page of theta functions. Can you explain how the theta function changes to this case (if at all it applies) and can it be reduced to a closed form solution?

Comment: You can try using this to obtain the integral form: $$e^{-n^2}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2/4} e^{i~n~t} dt$$ Be careful about convergence and whether or not you can sum under the integral

Comment: For the series like this one you don't actually need any alternative definition, because it converges extremely fast, and you can compute however much digits you want simply by truncating it

Comment: For theoretical calculations, it would easier to use a closed form solution (if it exists). Right?

Comment: Not always, sometimes. You can just denote this sum by a letter and use it further on. What's really important are connections between different numbers and functions whether they have a closed form or not. Knowing that this series is a theta function is important but only because you can look up various other properties of theta functions as they are well studied... Otherwise, it's all just a bunch of symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the inverse of $e$ in your linked formula you get
 $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-n^2}} =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{n^2}}=\theta_3(0,e^{-1})$$
Wolfram alpha gives for the numerical value
$$\theta_3(0,e^{-1}) = 1.772637204826652153$$ and this deviates from $\sqrt{\pi}$ by $0.000183353921136.$